# Wolf cabbage and goat using dijkstra.

Tags: graph-theory, algorithms

A farmer has to cross a river with a wolf, a goat and a cabbage.
He has a boat, but in the boat he can take just one thing.
He cannot let the goat alone with the wolf or the goat with the cabbage. It’s obvious why.

What is the solution?

Ok So I know the two solutions and I arrived them with trial and error. Reaching dead ends and making smart moves. But I am interested to know the solution of this problem using Dijkstra's Algorithm. I do not know what my graph should represent and how to use the shortest path algorithm to solve this puzzle.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Let $W, G, C$ denote wolf, goat, cabbage.
Let $F$ be the farmer.
Here are all the possible states:
\begin{align*}
\newcommand{\sep}{\; \mid \;}
&1  & WGCF &\sep  &\text{(start)} \\
&2  &  &\sep WGCF &\text{(goal)} \\
&3  & WCF &\sep G \\
&4  & G &\sep WCF \\
&5  & WGF &\sep C \\
&6  & C &\sep WGF \\
&7  & GCF &\sep W \\
&8  & W &\sep GCF \\
&9  & GF &\sep WC \\
&10 & WC &\sep GF \\
\end{align*}
(In all other states either the wolf will eat the goat, or the goat will eat
the cabbage.)
This is a graph on $10$ vertices.
There are edges as follows:
\begin{align*}
1  &\to 10 \\
2  &\to 9 \\
3  &\to 6, 8, 10 \\
4  &\to 5, 7, 9 \\
5  &\to 4, 8 \\
6  &\to 3, 7 \\
7  &\to 4, 6 \\
8  &\to 3, 5 \\
9  &\to 2, 4 \\
10 &\to 1, 3 \\
\end{align*}

Here is the graph:

[image]

You can then apply Djikstra's algorithm as usual
(which is kind of silly, since the solution is obvious once you see the graph).

Comment: Thanks for your detailed answer. In this puzzle constructing a graph was trivial (just the permutations). In a slightly different puzzle :
We have a glass of 8 litre full of water and we have two empty glasses of 3 and 5 litre each. We want to divide 8 litre equally in two glasses. Here when I try to construct the nodes I happen to reach the solution. Then is there a point in using Dijkstra here ?

Comment: There are two solution paths: $$1\to10\to3\to\begin{matrix}6\to7\\ 8\to5\end{matrix}\to4\to9\to2$$

Comment: @MarioCarneiro Thanks for the catch.

Comment: @AnuragSharma That sounds like you could use djikstra on that, but you might want to ask a new question if you have a new question.  Anyways, I've drawn a graph in TikZ and added it to my answer.

Answer (score 2):

Design the states as $S | S'$ where $S$ denotes the objects on one side of the river and $S'$ denotes the objects on the other side of the river.

Example : $WC|G$ denotes wolf and cabbage is on one side and goat on the other.

Put the appropriate transitions and run Dijkstra's algorithm.

Comment: Appropriate transitions ?

Comment: By appropriate I mean the safe transitions.

Comment: So you say that the nodes will the safe states and the connections (edges) will be the paths connecting two states. In this graph I use Dijkstra's ?

Comment: Yes. That is my idea. You can draw it to get yourself better idea.

Comment: Can we extend similar approach to solve a different puzzle. A glass of 8 litre full of water and we have two empty glasses of 3 and 5 litre. We want to divide 8 litre equally in two glasses. What would be the method?

Comment: Whenever you can design a directed graph with a start and goal states, you can apply this method.

Comment: But in drawing the graph itself we get the solution. Then what is the point of using Dijkstra's ?

Comment: If you get solution directly, do not use any algorithm.

Comment: Yeah. But I'm trying to understand where to use such algorithms in case some puzzle is non trivial and trial and error doesn't work.

Comment: Where to use is situation dependent. You need to think whenever you get a new puzzle - which approach to try.

Answer (score 2):

Dijkstra himself simplified the example problem by noting the symmetry between wolf and cabbage, see http://www.cs.utexas.edu/users/EWD/videos/EWD4.mpg.

Comment: You tube link of what I presume is the same video: https://youtu.be/0kXjl2e6qD0?t=445

Answer (score 0):

I know this is old, but here's the answer formatted as a decision tree I made. Note: the cabbage is not denoted as 'C', but 'L' since I did the problem with lettuce instead of cabbage for a school project.

[image]